# Don't have permission to access /*******.php on this server

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have searched high to low for similar problems, yes theres many, although none of the help as helped.

All Files are uploaded to a live website, no Errors on using an XAMMP test sever, file permssions are set `744 r/w/x` for user `r/r` for *guest and group*, but when i go to access the files Don't have permission to access `/*******.php`

Is there somthing i've missed because i've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

htaccess file on live server - looks rather different!

```
Options +Indexes  
RemoveHandler .html  
RemoveType .html  
AddType text/html .html  
Satisfy any  
Order Deny,Allow  
Allow from **********  
Deny from all
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Access to /logs"
```

--------------------------------------- New edit---------------------
Right found out my problem, cant get permission to access the htaccess file, this link explains http://tips.webdesign10.com/web-hosting/why-you-should-never-use-1and1-com-hosting never use 1and1.

Comment: I'd say there's an issue with your live server apache configuration. Perhaps an incorrect Allow/Deny directive?

Comment: Check your httpd.conf file in Apache Folder or .htaccess file on your sites folder.

Comment: Is that the htaccess file on the live server? i've never had to edit one before so im not sure what to add. thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual host configuration and check that you have simliar to this:

```
<Directory "your/path/to/document/root">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Edit - added to the above post the current htaccess file, looks rather different from yours

Comment: In your htaccess in this line: Allow from ********** is a hostname, an IP, a range?? Are your Ip in the range? Can you change it fo "Allow from all" and check??

Comment: Its an IP itself, I ca'nt edit, delete, rename the file, or chane the permissions, Does that mean i have to talk to my hosting ? as i find it very strange i cant change that singular directory

Comment: Yes, I think you need to talk to your hosting to ask why you can't change the htacess file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've messaged them asking why they've set there web servers up like this, and if they can allow me permission or change it themselfs. will get back to you once this is sorted and thanks!